# Prevent TPaintBox flicker when resizing

Tags: delphi, c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I have a `TFrame` with some controls, and a `TPanel` which is a container for a `TPaintBox` where I draw video.

When I resize the frame, the image on the paintbox flickers because of the infamous background erasing.

I googled for hours and tried everything (setting the PaintBox's `ControlStyle` to `csOpaque`, setting the panel's `Brush` to `bsClear`, changing the panel to double buffered, setting the panel's `FullRepaint` to false, etc) but the only thing that does the trick is intercepting the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message in my frame:

```cpp
void __fastcall TFrameSample::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if (Message.Msg == WM_ERASEBKGND)
        Message.Result = 1;
    else
        TFrame::WndProc(Message);
}
```

However, this means nothing is being redrawn, including the frame's title bar and all its controls.

I know this is a very common problem, is there a solution at all?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you disable the style?

Comment: Good question @RemyLebeau. I just tested this and the answer is yes. I'll remove the reference to this in my Q.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I keep wondering if it is possible to intercept only the background erasing for the paint box or its ancestor panel? Another idea is to inherit from the panel and create a new panel that has it's background erasing disabled? Not sure if this makes sense..

Comment: you can subclass the public `WindowProc` property on a per-control basis at runtime. Or, you can derive a new class and override the virtual `WndProc()` method at compile-time.

Comment: Oh, just posted the answer and now see your comment. If you like to post the answer instead I'll remove mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in an old post by Remy Lebeau, see http://www.delphigroups.info/2/81/414040.html

> There are several different ways to intercept messages on a
> per-control. Deriving a new class is only one of them.  You could also
> subclass just the WindowProc property of an existing object instance.
> For example:
>
> ```
> private
>     OldWndMethod: TWndMethod;
>     procedure PanelWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
> constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
> begin
>     inherited Create(AOwner);
>     OldWndMethod := Panel1.WindowProc
>     Panel1.WindowProc := PanelWndProc;
> end;
> procedure TForm1.PanelWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
> begin
>     if Message.Msg = WM_ERASEBKGND then
>     begin
>         //...
>     end else
>         OldWndMethod(Message);
> end;
> ```